# Integration of $ \int_1^2 \frac{3x^3 + 3x^2 - 5x + 4}{3x^3 - 2x^2 +3x -2} \mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, partial-fractions

Evaluate $$\int_1^2 \frac{3x^3 + 3x^2 - 5x + 4}{3x^3 - 2x^2 +3x -2}\mathrm  dx$$I believe I should use the partial fractions technique to evaluate this integral, but I am not getting anywhere when I try it.

Comment: Numerical calculation via riemann integral gives 1.73884 as the result.

Comment: @tp1 You're correct; to be explicit, it's $1+\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{5}{2}-2(\arctan 2-\frac{\pi}{4})+\frac{2}{3}\ln 4$.

Comment: For a partial fraction approach, because the degree of the numerator is equal (or in general greater than) the degree of the denominator of the integrand, you need to use long division first.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $$\frac{3x^3 + 3x^2 - 5x + 4}{3x^3 - 2x^2 +3x -2}=\frac{3x^3 - 2x^2 +3x -2+\color{red}{5x^2-8x+6}}{3x^3 - 2x^2 +3x -2}=1+\frac{5x^2-8x+6}{3x^3 - 2x^2 +3x -2}$$ and $$3x^3-2x^2+3x-2=(3x-2)(x^2+1)$$ so $$\int_1^2\frac{3x^3 + 3x^2 - 5x + 4}{3x^3 - 2x^2 +3x -2}\,dx=[x]_1^2+\int_1^2\frac{5x^2-8x+6}{(3x-2)(x^2+1)}\,dx$$ Now can you use partial fractions?

Comment: You did this, at most, in twelve minutes. Very impressive.

Comment: Mistake spotted: Line 1, fraction two should be $+6$ not $-6$

Comment: @TheCount Thanks! It's just a matter of practice and once you're familiar with function fractions of the same degree then you can immediately spot the trick :)

Comment: @RhysHughes Edited, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}  \frac {3x^3 + 3x^2 - 5x + 4}{3x^3 -2x^2 + 3x - 2}
& = \frac {(3x^3 - 2x^2 + 3x - 2) + 5x^2 - 8x + 6}{3x^3 -2x^2 + 3x - 2}\\ \\
&\ = 1 + \frac{5x^2 - 8x + 6}{3x^3 -2x^2 + 3x - 2} \end{align}

Factor the denominator

$$3x^3 -2x^2 + 3x - 2 = (3x-2)(x^2 + 1)$$

$$\frac {5x^3 -8x^2 +6}{(3x-2)(x^2+1)} = \frac {A}{3x-2}+ \frac {Bx+C}{x^2 + 1}$$

The "obvious" way to do this..

$$5x^2 -8x +6 = Ax^2 + A + 3Bx^2 + (-2B+3C)x - 2C$$

Giving a system of equations:

\begin{align} A+3B &= 5\\
-2B+3C &= -8\\
A - 2C &= 6 \end{align}

Here is a trick which you may, or may not find easier.

$$\frac {5x^3 -8x^2 +6}{(3x-2)(x^2+1)} = \frac {A}{3x-2}+ \frac {Bx+C}{x^2 + 1}$$

Multiply through by $(3x-2)$

$$\frac {5x^3 -8x^2 +6}{(x^2+1)} = A+ \frac {Bx+C}{x^2 + 1}(3x-2)$$

and evaluate at $x = 2/3$

$$\frac{\frac{26}{9}}{\frac{13}{9}} = 2 = A \implies A = 2 $$

$$\frac {3x^3 + 3x^2 - 5x + 4}{3x^3 -2x^2 + 3x - 2} = 1 + \frac {2}{3x- 2} + \frac {x-2}{x^2+1}$$

Comment: (+1) Perfect as a continuation of my answer! Though you might want to use `$$` instead...

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit. I couldn't read any of that.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if it's unclear - I'm not sure how to get the polynomial division in Mathjax, if someone could advise me on how to do this it would be appreciated.

[image]
From here I'll use Mathjax however:
$$5x^2-8x+6=A(x^2+1)+B(3x-2)$$
Let $A=px+q, B=rx+s$. If $p>0$, this equation transforms into a cubic so $p=0$.

Hence $qx^2+q+(rx+s)(3x-2)=5x^2-8x+6$

Expanding and collecting like terms we get:
$$q+3r=5$$
$$3s-2r=-8$$
$$q-2s=6$$
I instantly checked $q=2$ and $r=1$ (seemed like an obvious first choice given the first statement) and it works with $s=-2$.

Hence: $$\frac{5x^2-8x+6}{(x^2+1)(3x-2)}=1+\frac{2}{3x-2}+\frac{x-2}{x^2+1}$$

Integrate these seperately and sum the results:
$$\int_1^2{1 dx}=\bigg[x\bigg]^2_1=1$$

$$\int_1^2{\frac{2}{3x-2}dx}=2\int_1^2{\frac{1}{3x-2}dx}=2\bigg[\frac 13\ln|3x-2|\bigg]^2_1=\frac 23\ln(4)=\frac 43\ln(2)$$

$$\int_1^2{\frac{x-2}{x^2+1}dx}=\int_1^2{\frac{x}{x^2+1}dx}-\int_1^2{\frac{2}{x^2+1}dx}$$
Note the first of those is of the form $\int{\frac{f'(x)}{2f(x)}dx}$, this integral therefore is $\bigg[\frac 12\ln|x^2+1|\bigg]^2_1=\frac 12(\ln5-\ln2)$

The second half requires *$u$-substitution*. Let $x=\tan(u)$, then $dx=\sec^2(u) du$. Our integral becomes:

$$2\int_{\tan^{-1}(1)}^{\tan^{-1}(2)}{\frac{1}{sec^2(u)}\cdot \sec^2(u) du}=2\bigg[1\bigg]^{\tan^{-1}(2)}_{\tan^{-1}(1)} \because 1+\tan^2(u)=\sec^2(u)$$
$$=2\tan^{-1}(2)-\frac \pi2\approx 0.6435 \text{(this is also $\tan^{-1}\bigg(\frac 34\bigg)$)}$$

Summing all we get:$$1+\frac 56 \ln(2)+ \frac 12 \ln(5)-2\tan^{-1}(2)+\frac \pi2$$

Comment: You're missing a factor of $2$ near the end: it should be $\ldots-2\tan^{-1}2 + \frac{\pi}2$.

Comment: I just noticed thanks. I'll edit it